# WinRT: Running concurrently two tasks that share resources

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am working on a WinRT C# application. I have an event that is raised 15-30 times per second. This event provides me with a byte array parameter (it is actually an image in byte[]):

```
void FrameArrived(object sender, byte[] pixels)
{
    // 1. Create a bitmap and render it on an <Image> element (UI thread).
    DisplayBitmap(pixels);

    // 2. Pass the byte array to a method for video recording.
    RecordBitmap(pixels);
}
```

Both `DisplayBitmap` and `RecordBitmap` are heavy processes and the UI gets slow.

If I only call one of these methods, everything works fine.

Remember, this event is raised 15-30 times per second.

I need a way to run both methods in parallel. I have tried using Dispatcher, Parallel.Invoke and ThreadPool with no good results.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are both of these just *reading* from the byte array? Is the byte array going to be reused/mutated after FrameArrived completes? Presumably DisplayBitmap needs to be on the UI thread, but RecordBitmap doesn't?

Comment: Hi Jon. The byte array is just used for displaying the bitmap and is also processed by the video recorder. I do not need it after the FrameArrived completes. DisplayBitmap renders the bitmap on an Image UI element, so I guess it has to run on the UI thread. Actually, I do not care, as soon as the result is smooth enough :)

Comment: Why not just pass "RecordBitmap" to a background thread (Task.Factory.StartNew or similar)?

Comment: If I understand the logic correctly, you should keep DisplayBitmap as is and have RecordBitmap push the pixel array into a thread safe list. Then have another thread that does nothing but process the items in the list. This will keep the recording of the pixel arrays in order.

Comment: McGarnale: I have done this, though the UI thread gets slow.
Jon: Could you elaborate more on your solution or give me a usage example? Thank you so much everyone :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to record the pixel arrays in order, then you cannot just start a new thread for every call of this function because there is no guarantee that the threads will be run in order. The idea is to push the items into a list as quick as possible and then let another thread process the items at its own rate. This will only help with the recording part of your code, if you are trying to render more images than the UI thread can handle, then that's another issue.

```
    void FrameArrived(object sender, byte[] pixels)
    {
        //push pixels into list
        lock (_pixelList)
        {
            _pixelList.Add(pixels);
        }
        _waitHandle.Set();


        // 1. Create a bitmap and render it on an <Image> element (UI thread).
        DisplayBitmap(pixels);

        // 2. Pass the byte array to a method for video recording.
        //RecordBitmap(pixels);
    }

    AutoResetEvent _waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    List<byte[]> _pixelList = new List<byte[]>();
    bool _stop = false;
    void StartProcessPixelsThread()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (!_stop)
            {
                _waitHandle.WaitOne();
                while (true)
                {
                    byte[] pixels;

                    lock (_pixelList)
                    {
                        if (_pixelList.Count > 0)
                        {
                            pixels = _pixelList[0];
                            _pixelList.RemoveAt(0);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    RecordBitmap(pixels);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    void StopProcessPixelsThread()
    {
        _stop = true;
        _waitHandle.Set();
    }
```

Comment: There is still a blocking issue that has to do with the RecordVideo function I am using. I managed to make it work using what @McGarnagle said. However, you are totally right that creating a new thread for every call does not guarantee they will run in order. I will work a little more with your proposed answer. Once again, thank you.

Comment: It sounds like your RecordBitmap method needs the UI thread as well.

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it using ConcurrentQueue. It is slightly different to what @Jon proposed. Once again, thank you everyone for your assistance!

```
// Stores the frames coming from different threads.
ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<byte[]>();

// Begins recording.
public void Start()
{
    if (!IsRecording)
    {
        IsRecording = true;
    }

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (IsRecording || _queue.Count > 0)
        {
            byte[] pixels;

            if (_queue.TryDequeue(out pixels))
            {
                RecordBitmap(pixels);
            }
        }
    });
}

// Stops recording.
public void Stop()
{
    if (IsRecording)
    {
        IsRecording = false;
    }
}

// Updates the frames (called from FrameArrived).
public void Update(byte[] pixels)
{
    _queue.Enqueue(pixels);
}
```